# Why can't I import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap

Tags: java, import

Here is my code:

```
package DavidPackages.Other;

import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentSkipListMap;

public class SkipListTest {
}
```

Here is the error I get:

```
cannot find symbol class ConcurrentSkipListMap
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What version of Java are you using? It's only available in Java 6 and newer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you're using Java 6.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentSkipListMap.html